# Why am I getting gibberish for http request body?

Tags: python-3.x, http, aws-lambda, slack-api

I'm trying to create a Slack bot that uses AWS lambda api gateway as the backend. However, the event payload I'm getting has an incomprehensible payload body.

In the example im following the body should be like

Am I supposed to decode the body somehow?

I'm following this guide exactly but I'm implementing the lambda function in python. I just don't know why my event isn't even getting the proper body.
https://youtu.be/XgFVzBNgidQ

Comment: Adding to what Alex said this looks like the encoded requests from a slash command request. Normally you should not need to encode those requests yourself, but it should be done automatically by your framework (e.g. flask). If you add your current code to the question I am sure people will be be happy to help you find a solution.

Comment: Even if you delete the text with the token, it will remain accessible through the history option. You need to change your verification token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload isn't gibberish it's just base64-encoded and can be decoded using a library or method that supports base64-decoding.  Here's the decoded value:

> token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&team_id=TSQ1S1YKB&team_domain=dankscape&channel_id=CSQ1S2D2M&channel_name=bot&user_id=UT078Q6BA&user_name=the.dankscape&command=%2Fecho2&text=hi+spec&response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2Fcommands%2FTSQ1S1YKB%2F921356743414%2Fv3ltAkqOhjOU8HyLiOiMmJkG&trigger_id=908962933297.908060066657.da505f8459f1102a090444d8934e188b

Comment: Hi i just realised my verification token is in the question. Could you please delete this.

Comment: @Qwertford token has been redacted